# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS sends an IPv6 NS message for link-local address for no obvious reason

Tags: linux-kernel, ipv6

After sending an ICMPv6 `echo request` message to random global address, my router sends my PC a `Neighbor Solicitation` message in order to make an association between its link local IPv6 address and a MAC address. My PC replies with `Neighbor Advertisement` and then the router replies with ICMPv6 `destination unreachable` because it doesn't have a default route. However, always 3-5 seconds later, my PC sends a `Neighbor Solicitation` message for link-local address of the router and router replies with `Neighbor Advertisement`:

```
$ tshark -r ND.pcapng
  1 0.000000000 fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 -> ff02::1:ff4d:9a05 ICMPv6 90 Neighbor Solicitation for 2001:6b0:b:0:21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 from 02:06:0a:0e:ff:f1
  2 0.000058000 2001:6b0:b:0:21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 -> fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 ICMPv6 90 Neighbor Advertisement 2001:6b0:b:0:21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 (sol, ovr) is at 00:1c:bf:4d:9a:05
  3 0.034501000 2a03:b0c0::206:a00:e:fff0 -> 2001:6b0:b:0:21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 ICMPv6 170 Destination Unreachable (no route to destination)
  4 5.006686000 fe80::21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 -> fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 ICMPv6 90 Neighbor Solicitation for fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 from 00:1c:bf:4d:9a:05
  5 5.020158000 fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 -> fe80::21c:bfff:fe4d:9a05 ICMPv6 82 Neighbor Advertisement fe80::206:a00:320e:fff1 (rtr, sol)
$
```

I mean the packets `4` and `5` in the packet capture above. Why does Linux do this? Is there a reason for such behavior? I'm using kernel `3.13.0-32-generic`.